# is it possible to update the values from $this->db->get()

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to update table after selecting an active record from codeigniter?

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Yes. $this->db->update('mytable', $data);  after your select.

Comment: you want whole row or just previous value of `updated column` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. just put a `$this->db->update('table_name', $update_data, $where_clause)`
after your select. Be sure to save the result of your select first so you don't lose that data to the update. Except you are using the result from your select to update the table.